# Prove $C = AB$ is not invertible.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose $A$ is a $2 × 1$ matrix and B is a $1 × 2$ matrix. Prove that $C = AB$ is not invertible. $C$ will be a $1 × 1$ matrix. But why does that mean it will not be invertible?

Comment: $C$ will be a $2\times 2$ matrix.

Comment: $C$ will be a $2\times 2$ matrix, not $1\times 1$. An $m\times n$ matrix times a $n\times p$ matrix is an $m\times p$ matrix.

Comment: Remember **RC Cola**. **R**ows first, then **C**olumns second in matrix notation.

Comment: That's brilliant Cameron.

Comment: @OriaGruber I wish I could claim credit for such an ingenious mnemonic. I learned it in linear algebra in undergrad.

Answer (score 4):

Let $A=(a\ \ \ b)^T$ and $B=(c \ \ \ d)$, then 
$$AB= \left(\begin{array}{cc} ac & ad \\ bc & bd\end{array}\right)$$
Now check the determinant of this matrix is zero.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the rank-nullility theorem, then all you have to do is find a non-zero vector in the kernel of $AB$. How about finding a vector in the kernel of $B$? If $B = (b_1,b_2)$ then $(-b_2,b_1)^T$ should work out just fine.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, $C$ is a $2\times 2$ matrix. The way to see that it is not invertible is to consider the following. Let $B = (a,b)$ and consider $B' = \left(\begin{array}{r} -b \\ a\end{array}\right)$. What can you say about $BB'$? How does this translate to $CB' = (AB)B'$?

> Here, $AB$ is like a "projection"; it takes the $B$ portion of a vector and gives you a vector in the direction of $A$.